# Get known position in one image to another using 8-point algorithm

Tags: computer-vision

I have two images and and know the position of a point in the first image. Now I want to get the corresponding position in the second image.

This is my idea:

- I can use algorithms such as `SIFT` to match keypoints (as seen in the image)
- I know the camera matrix using calibration with e.g. chessboards
- Using the 8 point algorithm I calculate the fundamental matrix `F`

Can I now use `F` to calculate the corresponding point?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fundamental matrix `F` alone is not enough. If you have a point on one image, you can't find its position on the second image, because it depends not only on configuration of the cameras, but also on the distance from the camera to that point.

This can also be seen from the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_matrix_(computer_vision)) `x2^T * F * x1 = 0`. If you know `x1` and `F`, then for `x2` you get equation `x2^T * b = 0`, where b = `F * x1`. This is an equation of a point `x2` lying on the line `b` (points `x1`, `x2` and line `b` are in homogeneous coordinates). Although you cant find the exact position of the point on the second image, you know that it must lie somewhere on that line.

Hartley and Zisserman have a great explanation these of these concepts in their book [*Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/%7Evgg/hzbook/). Be sure to check it out for more details.

Comment: What if my camera didn't move, but only rotated. Would it be possible to solve this without knowing the distance to the point of interest?

Comment: Yes, in that case it will be possible. That is how panorama stitching works. In this case the transformation between two images is homography with 3 degrees of freedom. The fundamental matrix is not needed, but having intrinsic camera matrix will be useful.

Comment: Take a look at *Rotational panorama update* in section 4.3 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/image-alignment-and-stitching-a-tutorial/